# How can I identify Double's with potentially lost precision?

Tags: swift, double, precision

(Using Swift 5.1 in Xcode 11.1), how can I guard against the failing test scenario below? Basically I want to be able to write an extension on `Double`, a computed property `potentiallyLostPrecision` that can determine between "good" `Double` in the passing test case `testPrecision17Decimals` and the "bad" `Double` in the failing test case `testPrecision18Decimals`.

I tried looking at ulp, significand, comparing `nextUp` with self, and looking at `mantissa`, `exponent`etc, but I could not come up with anything that worked.

```swift
import Foundation
import XCTest

class DecimalPrecisionTests: XCTestCase {

    func testPrecision13Decimals() {

        doTestSmallDecimals(
            smallest: 0.0102030405054,
            aDecimal: 0.0102030405055,
            greatest: 0.0102030405056
        )
    }

    func testPrecision16Decimals() {

        doTestSmallDecimals(
            smallest: 0.0102030405060705,
            aDecimal: 0.0102030405060706,
            greatest: 0.0102030405060707
        )
    }

    func testPrecision17Decimals() {

        doTestSmallDecimals(
            smallest: 0.01020304050607065,
            aDecimal: 0.01020304050607066,
            greatest: 0.01020304050607067
        )
    }

    // This test fails
    func testPrecision18Decimals() {

        doTestSmallDecimals(
            smallest: 0.010203040506070805,
            aDecimal: 0.010203040506070806,
            greatest: 0.010203040506070807
        )
    }

}

private extension DecimalPrecisionTests {

    func doTestSmallDecimals(
        smallest: Double,
        aDecimal: Double,
        greatest: Double
    ) {

        XCTAssertGreaterThan(greatest, aDecimal)
        XCTAssertGreaterThan(aDecimal, smallest)

        XCTAssertLessThan(smallest, aDecimal)
        XCTAssertLessThan(aDecimal, greatest)
    }

}
```

Comment: You can only lose precision in a *calculation* (addition, multiplication, ...) with doubles. Given only a floating point value, there is no way to tell if it is the result of a calculation which “lost precision.”

Comment: but how come test `testPrecision18Decimals()` fails? Is it because of limitations of the `XCTAssertGreaterThan `?

Comment: Binary floating point numbers cannot represent all decimal fractions exactly. `aDecimal` and `greatest` are the *same* values.

Comment: Specifically, they are both closer to 0.01020304050607080681434268853990943171083927154541015625 than to any other number an IEEE 754 64-bit float can represent. For this purpose, conversion from decimal to float is a calculation than show rounding error.